# Opencart how to add everything from the language file in php loop

Tags: opencart

It there a way to read everything from within a language with Opencart?

At the moment I have to:

```
Controller
$this->load->language('help');          
$this->data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');    
$this->data['tab1'] = $this->language->get('tab1');
```

Language File

```
<?php
// Heading
$_['heading_title']      = 'Help';
$_['tab1'] = 'Account';    
?>
```

Comment: why you would like to do so ?
this will pollute your $this->data array

Comment: Yes I thought of this and added everything to $this->data['language'] to prevent anything getting overwritten.

Comment: i think should be added to the core of opencart, in the controller class i think,or improving the language class it self

Comment: If you do this at the top of your controller, then it will not "pollute" your data array whatsoever. This is actually how a lot of developers do this these days, including myself

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to use array merge at the top of your controller

```
$this->data = array_merge($this->data, $this->language->load('language/file'));
```

or simply

```
$this->data += $this->language->load('language/file');
```

### Edit

For 2.x, use

`$data = array_merge($this->data, $this->language->load('language/file'));`

3.x does this automatically

Comment: For anyone working in newer versions of OpenCart: Same method applies to 2.x by using `$data` (instead of `$this->data`). Behavior is automatic as of 3.x.

Comment: Thanks @Mavelo - I've updated the answer accordingly

Comment: @JayGilford You're welcome. In OC 2.x, I like using `$data = $this->load->language('extension/module/customer_sale_popup');` as long as it's done before any other changes to `$data` :)

Comment: @Mavelo yeah I pretty much do that myself

Answer (score 0):

In system/library/language.php is a 
function to get everything called all().

This is how to get a single item:

```
$var = $this->language->get('heading_title');
```

This returns an array with all language entries:

```
$var = $this->language->all();
```

Comment: Note: `Language::all()` is not available in 1.5.x. Its use is discouraged in 2.x according to the "dont use" comment in the class' code. The function however persists in 3.x and has been used in the core in `ControllerEventLanguage::before()` so apparently it's here to stay :P